# What is the origin and usage of the phrase רבונו של עולם?

Tags: tefilla

I don't recall the phrase   - רבונו של עולם -  (loose meaning- "Master of the world") mentioned in Tana"ch. I think it first appears in the Mishnah or Gemarra. It is a common phrase in prayers.

When was this phrase first used? What does this phrase convey that couldn't be conveyed by just אד-ני ? I.e. - are there special occasions or situations that make the choice of this phrasing more optimal or more appropriate?

Comment: How about HaKadosh Baruch Hu? Nu, Hashem is referred to by many names, as in English...

Comment: @ezra Didn't think of that one. It's another one that I think is Mishanic in origin, I believe.

Comment: I see no evidence that it was anything other than one of numerous common expression referring to God. What sort of evidence are you looking for? Those three examples in Tannaic literature hardly seem enlightening, and I doubt other examples would be any more enlightening on why one common reference, rather than some other common reference is used.

Comment: @mevaqesh Thanks for the 3 references. B"N, I'll view them, later. They may offer some ideas to edit the question and improve it. I'm looking for something that may indicate why this phrasing was invented or if it may have been used in specific situations. Perhaps, there isn't any. I can't judge well until I view these.

Comment: The phrase is present in Tannaic literature: Mishna Ta'anit 3:8, Tosefta Sotah 6:5, and 6:7.